# Some problems with testing Akka.net

Tags: akka.net

- **Version Akka.NET v1.3.8**
- **Version Akka.TestKit.NUnit3 v1.3.2**
- **Version NUnit v3.10.1**
- **Platform Windows 10**

I have an actor of the following kind:

```
public class BranchUsersActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public BranchUsersActor()
    {
        Receive<UserBeingOnline>((online) =>
        {
            var userActorName = $"user_{online.UserId}";
            if (Context.Child(userActorName).Equals(ActorRefs.Nobody))
            {                
                var user = Context.ActorOf(UserActor.Props(online.UserId, online.BranchId), userActorName);
                user.Tell(online);                    
            }
        });
    }

    public static Props Props(LoggingTags tags)
    {
        return Akka.Actor.Props.Create(() => new BranchUsersActor(tags));
    }
}
```

When testing this actor, I expect that I will have a child actor.
I'm writing the next test to check this situation (using the NUnit framework):

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var branchUserActor = Sys.ActorOf(BranchUsersActor.Props());
    branchUserActor.Tell(UserBeingOnline.Create(userId, branchId));

    var expectedChildActor = Sys.ActorSelection($"{actorPath}/user_{userId.AkkaPrepare()}")
        .ResolveOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Result;

    Assert.IsNotNull(expectedChildActor);
}
```

I expect that within a second I will receive the child actor on the specified path, but I get *ActorNotFoundExpection*.

If I'm doing something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var branchUserActor = Sys.ActorOf(BranchUsersActor.Props());
    branchUserActor.Tell(UserBeingOnline.Create(userId, branchId));

    Task.Delay(100).ContinueWith(_ => 
    {
        var expectedChildActor = Sys.ActorSelection($"{actorPath}/user_{userId.AkkaPrepare()}")`enter code here`
            .ResolveOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Result;
    }
    Assert.IsNotNull(expectedChildActor);    
}
```

This works fine, but 1 of 10 times the test falls, because I get an *ActorNotFoundException*.
But I wonder why the first option does not work the way I expect?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```csharp
branchUserActor.Tell(UserBeingOnline.Create(userId, branchId));

var expectedChildActor = Sys.ActorSelection($"{actorPath}/user_{userId.AkkaPrepare()}")
  .ResolveOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Result;
```

The problem here is that when you're telling `UserBeingOnline`, you're triggering an asynchronous action - a message has been send to `branchUserActor`, but it may not have been processed right away. In the meantime you're calling resolve one, which tells actor system to find a child of `branchUserActor` - a child, which is not yet there, since the parent didn't handle the message yet.

You can use [AwaitAssert(() => Assert.IsNotNull(ResolveChild()))](http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/C6A1034F.htm) method to work with that.